# Get node name with REXML

Tags: ruby, rexml

I have an XML, which can be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testnode type="1">123</testnode>
```

or like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<othernode attrib="true">other value</othernode>
```

or the root node can be something completely unexpected. (Theoretically anything.)
I'm using REXML to parse it. How can I find out what XML node is the root element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
xml = REXML::Document.new "<?xml version" #etc (or load from file)
root_node = xml.elements[1]
root_node_name = root_node.name
```

Comment: Thanks. In my defense it is not in the documentation. Or at least I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to find it in the docs either - I had to Google in the end.